# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'users' is not a registered namespace inside 'v1'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, namespaces

#main url

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/v1/', include('users.api.urls',namespace='v1')),
```

]

#app url

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ExampleView

app_name='users'

urlpatterns=[
path("", ExampleView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

## app view

```
from rest_framework.views import Response, APIView


class ExampleView(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    return Response({"message": "hello world"})
```

## test app

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APISimpleTestCase


class TestUser(APISimpleTestCase):

def setUp(self):

    self.path1 = reverse('v1:users:home')

def test_user_path(self):
    print(self.path1)
```

what is wrong with this code? why it return **django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'users' is not a registered namespace inside 'v1'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
reverse('v1:home')
```

You have already changed the namespace of `users` to `v1`. Since users is not a URL path name in the *app's* `urls.py`, you get an error.